# How to pass hidden information in a form in html?

Tags: php, html, forms, textarea, submit

How do I pass hidden information about a form?

```
<form action="index.php" method="post">
    <textarea rows="2" cols="30"  NAME="com" >
    </textarea>
    <input type="submit" name="com_submit" value="com" />
</form>
```

I need see that the comment is passed for which type of post so I need to pass the value of variable $type also by this form so how should I do that?

I am a beginner so i am sorry if i am asking any stupid question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a [hidden field](http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/input.hidden.html):

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="theFormType" />
```

The user will not see hidden inputs on the form.

If the value of the hidden form comes from php, you can use this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="form_type" value="<?php echo $type ?>" />
```

Answer (score 0):

if i understand correctly you want to use the hidden input 
[hidden input](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type.asp) a great summary from w3schools