# How can I hide the value from a input, so that the value is still accesable but won't be displayed?

Tags: html, forms, input

I have a simple input form from the type submit and it contains the value $username:

```html
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
     <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="'.$username.'">
</form>
```

How can I hide the value, so that it will not be displayed on index.php, but I still can access this value?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass hidden information in a form in html?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17014129/how-to-pass-hidden-information-in-a-form-in-html)

Comment: @mx0 i have already seen this but that didnt help me because with type="hidden"  even the button wont be displayed. So the button should be displayed but the value not

Comment: Put username in `<input type="hidden" name="user_name" value="'.$username.'" />` and set change button value to *Submit*.

Comment: @mx0 Hey that solved my problem thank you! Do you want to pin it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To hide fields in form from displaying change their type to `hidden`. Keep in mind that `hidden` field is just not displayed but anyone can read it/change it with browser devtools.

```
<form action="index.php" method="POST">
     <input type="hidden" name="user_name" value="'.$username.'">
     <input class="submit" type="submit" name="submitbtn" value="Submit">
</form>
```